# Had to reinstall SP Designer, now when I open a workflow it appears blank

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I had a workflow running and published on my site that I created with sharepoint designer, however designer kept crashing and I had to reinstall it and now when I open the workflow it appears empty...what can I do? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Had to download Microsoft hotfix.

Comment: can you provide which one?

Comment: I don't remember the code but if you refresh windows update it should appear right there.